# Regex nested tags

Tags: c#, regex, nested, tags

I want to parse the following text with *Regex* by the function tag.

```xml
Anwers: <function>2+2
                 <function>1+3</function> 
        </function>.  
Thanks for your time. 
<function>sayGoodbye() 
         <function>10*10</function> 
         writeYourName()
</function>
```

Below is a recursive method that should transform the given text into:

Answers: 44 .
    Thanks for your time. 
    Goodbye 100 Rex.

```cs
private static readonly string TagFormulaStart = "<function>";
private static readonly string TagFormulaEnd = "</function>";

public static string Calculate(string formula)
{
    var pattern = string.Format("{0}(((.|\r|\n)*?)){1}", TagFormulaStart, TagFormulaEnd);
    var matches = Regex.Matches(formula, pattern);

    if (matches.Count == 0)
    {
        return formula;
    }
    else
    {
        var firstAppearanceOfTAG = matches[0].ToString();
        var formulaToCalculate = firstAppearanceOfTAG.Replace(TagFormulaStart, string.Empty).Replace(TagFormulaEnd, string.Empty);
        var result = BgProcessorLib.Evaluator.EvaluateString(formulaToCalculate, null, false);

        formula = formula.Replace(firstAppearanceOfTAG, result);

        return Calculate(formula);
    }
}
```

The problem is that my regex `/<function>(((.|\r|\n)*?))<\/function>/igm` in case of nested tags will stop at the first occurrence of the end of function tag.

I attached a picture to make it clearer.

[image]

Comment: If you work in C# and use .NET regex, testing a regex at a site that only supports JS regex is meaningless.

Comment: Are you sure you want parse XML with regexes? There are a lot of ready "wheels", calling XML parsers.

Comment: @NikolayProkopyev it is not an XML.

Comment: XML and HTML are not "regular languages" (in the technical sense). Therefore regular expressions cannot, in general, process them (even in their massively extended state beyond the original idea of regular expressions). Use a parser instead. Sticking to regexes might have [consequences[(http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use http://regexr.com/ for testing my regex

Comment: @POIR, if you only add a surrounding <root> Anwers: <function>2+2 ... </root> element, it will immedialtely become :)

Comment: @POIR: You won't be able to test balanced constructs at regexr.

Comment: Ok. I see that it is not a good ideea to use regex in my case, but what is your recomandation in this matter?

Comment: @POIR: It is not clear why the output should have `Goodbye 100 Rex.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend solving this via RegEx, if you really want to, you have to tell your Regex not to include another opening tag, e.g.:

```
<function>((?!<function>).)*?<\/function>
```

<sub>Warning: terrible performance, for educational purposes only!</sub>

Also, you should escape your input:

```
var pattern string.Format("{0}((?!{0}).)*?{1}", 
    Regex.Escape(TagFormulaStart), 
    Regex.Escape(TagFormulaEnd));

var matches = Regex.Matches(formula, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

---

This will not account for a lot of realistic use-cases, so again: I wouldn't recommend using RegEx in this particular case.

[Online-Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ljNjcl/1)
[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/4EkOeU)

Comment: "Educational" hint: never use `(.|\r|\n)*?` inside a pattern. Just use `RegexOptions.Singleline` and a mere `.` will match any char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right! I totally forgot about that one ^^

Answer (score 0):

About XML approach.

At first, make your source valid XML, i.e. add surrounding `<root> Answer <function... </root>` root tag.

Then use a parser like [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx#xlinqoverview_topic3)

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(sourceString);

foreach (var funct in root.Descendants("function")).ToList() {
   var evaluated = evaluate(funct.InnerText); // evaluate should be defined before
   funct.InnerText = evaluated;
}

var result = root.ToString();
```

Then you can just replace out all tags with regex or simple string replace (remove everything between brackets <>). Probably, XML Linq also has a ready tool for that, but i don't know.